Creation of GridDB Time Series table not working (precision)
I'm testing out Kafka with GridDB and I wanted to create a time series table with a precision of nanoseconds (labeled as TIMESERIES(6)) but whenever I run the sql query into the CLI, i'm met with an error. I'm wondering if perhaps this is a CLI Error and if I wrote a short java method it'd work out?
Here is my SQL query:
create table meter_3 (timestamp TIMESTAMP(6) PRIMARY KEY, kwh DOUBLE, temp DOUBLE ) USING TIMESERIES;
USING TIMESERIES makes it a time_series container and the 6 in the col type of typestamp sets the precision level as indicated above. when I run this, I get the following error
D20332: An unexpected error occurred while executing a SQL. : msg=[[60015:DS_DS_SCHEMA_INVALID] Execute SQL failed (reason=CREATE TABLE failed (reason=Type of rowkey not supported)

so I removed the PRIMARY KEY indication because perhaps it's redundant with a time series container (it's already a feature)
but I get another error:
D20332: An unexpected error occurred while executing a SQL. : msg=[[60015:DS_DS_SCHEMA_INVALID] Execute SQL failed (reason=CREATE TABLE failed (reason=must define one rowkey) 

I suppose worst case I can remove the time_series container designation and use this as a collection container? But does anybody know how to get around this?

Any reason why you don't want to have a primary key in your table, even if it's GridDB?

sorry, I was unclear in my original comment. I tried removing the primary key just in case that was the thing causing the error. The primary key in time series container is mandatory so I was thinking maybe it was causing an error: kind of  a long shot way of trying to resolve this issue but it was wrong
